# Compiler error when using "= delete" in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have this class that, when compiled, gives out C2059 and C 2238 ';' both errors on both lines. Why this code doesn't compile?

```
class bitreader
{
    std::istream& §is;
    std::uint8_t §buff;
    int §n;

    uint32_t read()
    {
        if (§n == 0) {
            §buff = §is.get();
            §n = 8;
        }

        §n--;

        return (§buff >> §n) & 1;
    }

public:

    bitreader(std::istream& os)
        : §is(os)
        , §n(0)
    {}

    // The following two lines produce errors
    bitreader(const bitreader& rhs) = delete;
    bitreader& operator=(const bitreader& rhs) = delete;

    uint32_t operator()(uint32_t n)
    {
        uint32_t val = 0;

        while (n-- > 0)
            val = (val << 1) | read();

        return val;
    }

    std::istream& operator()(uint32_t& val, uint32_t n)
    {
        val = 0;
        while (n-->0)
            val = (val << 1) | read();

        return §is;
    }
};
```

I add that the same code compiles without any issue on my friend's Visual Studio. NOTE: If I comment the lines the code compiles.

Comment: That's an interesting data member naming scheme.

Comment: Because my university's machines have that installed and we cannot install what we want. So if I want to pass the exam I  have to deal with the version installed in the labs

Comment: Please indent your code properly so that we can read it.

Comment: Also you should have constructed a [MCVE] - you only need a very small program to show that `= delete` isn't working. The majority of your posted code is irrelevant. Having shown to yourself that the problem was `= delete`, you'd then have performed _research_ to find out what the issue is with `= delete` in VS2012, and likely found the answer yourself. I originally upvoted this question for being well-formed, but I've changed my mind due to lack of research effort.

Comment: @user3416648 - *Because my university's machines have that installed and we cannot install what we want.* -- Well get ready for many more problems if  your friend has VS 2015, and the code fails to compile for 2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The `=delete` specifier is a C++11 feature that Visual Studio 2012 does not support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Either upgrade your Visual Studio to a newer version, or remove the `=delete` and make those two declarations private.